# Birthday problem modified: Expected number of birthdays

Tags: combinatorics, birthday

Given there are N people in one room and let us assume that they are born randomly on one of x(=365) days in the year. What is the expected number of different birthdays for N people?

Edit:
I think the solution should be x-x(1-1/x)^n since (1-1/x)^n is the prob. that no-one has their birthday on a specific day and since all days are the same we should be able to multiply this probability with the number of days to get the expected number of "no birthday" days.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you really think this problem hasn't been solved many times on the web?

Comment: I don't find this specific question: I would be happy if you would then share a link if it was shown somewhere :)

Comment: Start with evaluating the probability that $k$ people have different birthdays.

Comment: I have a solution for that.

Comment: @callculus "evaluate the probability that $k$ people have different birthdays", that is a horrible suggestion for this problem.  It will lead to an answer... yes... but the answer will be in such a clunky unwieldy format that it is practically unusable.  Linearity of expectation is a far superior approach here.

Comment: Start here, then follow links:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $X_1, X_2,\dots, X_{365}$ be indicator random variables taking value $1$ if their respective day of the year is the birthday of at least one of the $N$ people and $0$ otherwise.

How can we rephrase the meaning of the random variable $X=X_1+X_2+X_3+\dots+X_{365}$ in more natural language?

> $X$ is the random variable denoting the number of distinct birthdays seen amongst our $N$ people.

If we were to look at $E[X]$, noting its relation to $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_{365}$, how can this help us for our problem?

> $E[X] = E[X_1+X_2+\dots+X_{365}]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]+\dots+E[X_{365}]$ by linearity of expectation.

What more is left to complete the problem?

> Calculate $E[X_i]$, notice the symmetry of the scenario, and complete the necessary arithmetic.

Comment: So E[X_i] should be 1-(1-1/x)^n ?

Comment: With $x$ as the number of days in your year you are considering, yes.

Comment: Okay, thanks for elaborating my problem! :) Now I'm more sure about the result.